# QPainterPath stroke artifacts

Tags: qt, qpainter, qpainterpath

I am putting together a `QPainterPath` with text, then I'm drawing it, first with `QPainter::strokePath`, then with `QPainter::fillPath`. However, the stroke exhibits artefacts, as shown in the image. Anything I am doing wrong/how to prevent this? Should I report it as a bug?
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that instead of using `strokePath` and `fillPath`, the following code works without artefacts and is even faster to render:

```
if(outlineEnabled) {
    p.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
    p.setPen(QPen(outlineColor, outlineWidth/scaleFactor, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin));
    for(const auto &polygon : path.toSubpathPolygons())
        p.drawPolygon(polygon, Qt::OddEvenFill);
}

p.setBrush(color);
p.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
for(const auto &polygon : path.toFillPolygons())
    p.drawPolygon(polygon, Qt::OddEvenFill);
```